# Difference between using vector polymorphically vs. arrays polymorphically

Tags: c++, boost

Based on More Effective C++ **Item 3:  Never treat arrays polymorphically**, we should avoid treating an array polymorphically.

So why we can use `std::vector` to hold pointers pointing to the base class without problems?

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
#include <vector>

class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void PrintMe() const {
        std::cout << "BaseClass" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~BaseClass() {}
};

class SubClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void PrintMe() const {
        std::cout << "SubClass" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass> > vecPtrs;
    boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass> shp1(new BaseClass);
    vecPtrs.push_back(shp1);

    boost::shared_ptr<BaseClass> shp2(new SubClass);
    vecPtrs.push_back(shp2);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vecPtrs.size(); ++i)
    {
        vecPtrs[i]->PrintMe();
    }
}

// Output:

BaseClass
SubClass
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: No difference. You could store the pointers in an array as well. The text is probably about not storing different types of objects directly in the array. That doesn't work with a vector either.

Comment: My question is about to store pointers of different subclass of a baseclass into a container.

Comment: *an array polymorphically* sounds very weird to me.  You are using *polymorphically* as a noun when it is clearly an adverb?

Comment: @thang: Most sentences sound a bit weird if you accidentally a word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's fine to use either an array or vector to hold *pointers* to polymorphic types.

The problem is if you try to treat an array of *objects* polymorphically. Array access via a pointer uses the pointer type to determine the size of the array objects, which will go horribly wrong if the pointer type does not match the object type.

```
Base * stuff = new Derived[10]; // No compile error: pointer conversion is allowed
stuff[2].do_something();        // Still no compile error, but weird runtime errors.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing magic about `std::vector`. A regular array holding pointers to base classes will work just the same.

Comment: My question is focus on polymorphism.

Comment: @q0987: The problems array have with polymorphism are the same that vector have.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:

```
struct base {
    int element;
};

struct derived : base {
    int another_element;
};

void f(base *p) {
    std::cout << (void*)&p[1] << '\n';
}

int main() {
    derived array[20];
    std::cout << (void*)&array[1] << '\n';
    f(array);
    return 0;
}
```

If you run this program you'll get two **different** addresses for the element at index 1 in the array.

This happens because at the point of the call to `f`, the name `array` decays into a pointer to its first element. That's a `derived*`, and the compiler **converts** that pointer into a `base*` and passes it to `f`. Inside `f`, pointer arithmetic treats the passed-in pointer as a `base*`. `p[1]` points to an object whose address is `sizeof(base)` bytes above `p`, that is, it points into the middle of the first `derived` object in the array.

So anything you do with array elements other than the first will give you nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying you shouldn't do this:

```
Base array[N];
array[0] = Derived1();
array[1] = Derived2();
```

These derived objects will be sliced when they are placed in the array.

The exact same is true for a standard container like `std::vector`. For polymorphic behaviour in C++, you need to use pointers:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> array[N];
array[0].reset(new Derived1());
array[1].reset(new Derived2());
```